# Craft CMS 3 - Redis Sessions cause error

Tags: craft3, cache, session, redis

I've configured Redis to handle cache and sessions for Craft 3, and while cache configuration is working as expected, I had to disable session configuration due to the below error.

It fails on the method *getAssetBundleFlashes*

Are there any other settings (e.g. for PHP) that may be required?

Here is my Redis component config in *config/app.php* for Yii 2 (yes I've added the yii2-redis package to my composer file too).

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'redis' => [
            'class' => yii\redis\Connection::class,
            'hostname' => getenv('REDIS_HOSTNAME'),
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'session' => [
            'class' => yii\redis\Session::class,            
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => yii\redis\Cache::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\UnknownMethodException: Calling unknown method: yii\redis\Session::getAssetBundleFlashes() in /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:300
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(896): yii\base\Component->__call('getAssetBundleF...', Array)
#1 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(818): craft\web\View->registerAssetFlashes()
#2 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/exception.php(526): craft\web\View->endBody()
#3 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(336): require('/srv/craft/vend...')
#4 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(254): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/srv/craft/vend...', Array)
#5 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(266): yii\base\View->renderFile('/srv/craft/vend...', Array, Object(craft\web\ErrorHandler))
#6 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(126): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array)
#7 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(156): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\UnknownMethodException))
#8 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): craft\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\UnknownMethodException))
#9 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(71): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\UnknownMethodException))
#10 [internal function]: craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\UnknownMethodException))
#11 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\UnknownMethodException: Calling unknown method: yii\redis\Session::getAssetBundleFlashes() in /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:300
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(896): yii\base\Component->__call('getAssetBundleF...', Array)
#1 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(818): craft\web\View->registerAssetFlashes()
#2 /srv/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/0b/0b226b9457e83d59f4ca4ab9c0a794a8e7489d0fa5850859e4263059d8eeeb71.php(63): craft\web\View->endBody()
#3 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_dcb3cad6f26dfdd9b0c18a08e2464625842a6825bf5d95797cfd4aff7f9d3ba1->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#4 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#5 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#6 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#7 /srv/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/92/928ab9c5030f542894551fd742424701943b57966d99233b0de96b7fd7dbc7fa.php(40): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#8 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_566de35bd43d5ce1cf719a311929c2acf2baa3debb31cbeb7c6967ed2e3324cd->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#9 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#10 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#11 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#12 /srv/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/df/df104a4367ddd257c886d6ca86296f015495978d68f657dc29d28b6b8d55ad76.php(94): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#13 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_9f1f09a6b58c9f64d0f79651ec01d22c48213d3eb6b8317580edaa5e0f09bc62->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#14 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#15 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#16 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#17 /srv/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/b9/b93d72fd3873b8f06d39c6630e8e2d8fcfadfd6798468d109266fec4e37c1dfe.php(32): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#18 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(390): __TwigTemplate_19451c5d966903f571459e857efabdca189708bebe8e4a3b3611e8d1061509a9->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#19 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#20 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(367): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#21 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#22 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(375): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array)
#23 /srv/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(289): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#24 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(305): Twig_Environment->render('dashboard/_inde...', Array)
#25 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(352): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('dashboard/_inde...', '[<span class="s...')
#26 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(113): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('dashboard/_inde...', '[<span class="s...')
#27 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/DashboardController.php(135): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('dashboard/_inde...', Array)
#28 [internal function]: craft\controllers\DashboardController->actionIndex()
#29 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#30 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#31 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(74): yii\base\Controller->runAction('index', Array)
#32 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('index', Array)
#33 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(238): yii\base\Module->runAction('dashboard/index', Array)
#34 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('dashboard/index', Array)
#35 /srv/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(227): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#36 /srv/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#37 /srv/craft/web/index.php(30): yii\base\Application->run()
#38 {main}
```

Comment: Having the same issue using yii\redis\Session…

Setting session.save_handler, session.save_path in php.ini works, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@boboldehampsink to the rescue: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3428

---

**Update:**

This article covers things really well.
https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session

**php ini config**

```
[Session]
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

**configurable in /../craft/web/index.php**

```
define('REDIS_HOSTNAME', getenv('REDIS_HOSTNAME') ?: 'localhost');
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'redis');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tcp://'.REDIS_HOSTNAME.':6379');
```

Comment: Sorry, link is dead.